# How can I include/extend a jade file from the root of my template directory in express?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Given a sample structure:

```
/layout.jade
/really/deep/dir/inside/my/template/folder/example.jade
```

Is there any way I can extend layout.jade in example.jade without having to keep track of the number of parent directories?

This works as intended tho:

```
extends ../../../..etc../../../layout
```

But it would be preferable to do something like:

```
extends /layout
```

Or even alias/hardlink and use it like:

```
extends layout
```

Also assuming somebody knows a solution, can it also be applied to include?

Comment: Ran into this same issue. Ended up using the nasty "../../.." approach but I'm surprised this hasn't been dealt with in a more pleasing way yet.

Comment: @JoshPinter see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a change that was introduced in [this particular commit](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/commit/d740ba7cec7b30ce7519e107467cfa0b87ffcdaa).

Basically, if the first character found in the include statement is a forward slash and basedir is defined, it will look for the template in that path.

You must first setup Jade:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.locals.basedir = app.get('views');
```

Then, from any template, no matter how deeply nested, you can do:

```
include /layout
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the code itself, I realized that someone can't simply reference a jade file relevant to the templates root.

However, a simple approach is to patch jade/lib/parser.js replacing two instances of:

```
, dir = dirname(this.filename);
```

With:

```
, dir = path.indexOf('/') ? dirname(this.filename) : this.options.settings.views;
```

I might as well warn you that this is not tested enough and is not intended for production use.